# Posting jQuery slider result value with html form / php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery, which is a slider with one resulting value, which results a variable:

```
var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
$("#amount").html(value);
```

I need to use the result in my php code, checking whether this is in a range or not, or make some mathematical stuff with it.

How can I get the value nice and easy?
like

```
$value= ... (slider value)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed as though you are trying to get the value of the slider when the form is submitted.

Seems to now be working, here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LETvH/

This was accomplished by editing your code a little bit and adding

```
          $("[name='amount']").val(ui.value);
```

Be sure to change that input field back to "hidden" from "text"

Comment: Works fine, thank you. I wonder why the -1.

Comment: The question was a bit too beginner for this site unfortunately, really though it seemed like this question would not help future readers, so basically on a google search we would not want this popping up as its just a coding mistake on your end, not something that generally needs to be solved, or is common enough for google to take the title and find your post. Sorry, I was not the one who down voted you though.